# Is MacBook Pro 2016's screen stain proof?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Want to buy a MacBook Pro. But afraid of `Staingate`. Do anybody heard about stain on MBP 2016 [like it was on older MBPs](http://www.staingate.org/)?

Comment: Non-issue. Haven't actually seen this ever and I'm constantly around macbooks.

Comment: Non issue? Apple replaced many displays because of this.

Comment: My MBP has staingate issue. I live in India where there are not official Apple stores. Only Authorised apple stores where they don't do any "official" replacements.